Unable to Configure Service ID for Apple Sign In with AWS Cognito due to Existing App ID
I am currently trying to set up Apple Sign In with AWS Cognito user pools, but I am facing some issues.
Problem Overview:
When setting up the Service ID in the Apple Developer portal, I encounter the following error and cannot complete the setup:
An App ID with Identifier 'com.myTeamName.myAppName' is not available. Please enter a different string.

Additionally, since the app is already registered in my Apple Developer account, I cannot configure the Service ID and receive the following error when attempting to delete and recreate the App ID:
There is a problem with the request entity
The App ID 'com.myTeamName.myAppName' appears to be in use by the App Store, so it can not be removed at this time.

Steps Taken:
I followed the steps in this guide: AWS Amplify - Add Social Provider

Signed in with my Apple developer credentials.
Selected "Certificates, IDs, & Profiles" on the main developer portal page.
Selected "Identifiers" from the left navigation bar and then "Service IDs" from the drop-down list on the right.
Selected the Service ID created according to the guide.

Issue:
As mentioned, the existing App ID is already in use, so I cannot set up the new Service ID. This prevents me from completing the setup and linking Apple Sign In with AWS Cognito user pools.
Request:
I would appreciate any support or guidance on resolving this issue. Specifically, I need help with setting up a new Service ID using the existing App ID or any alternative solutions to bypass this error.
Thank you for your assistance.

If I get it right what you mean, you're trying to create a new Service ID and getting the error message as you mentioned?
I can easily reproduce it when I input any existing values in the Identifier field. The confusing part is the error message says App ID, but it isn't necessarily App ID, which means if you already have another Service IDs that has the same Identifier, it also results in an error and the error message says App ID.

Anyway, you can't create a new Service ID with the Identifier that is same as any identifier e.g. App ID, Service ID, etc. So, double check you input the unique value in Identifier field.

Thank you so much. I had an assumption that App ID and Service ID should be the same. So I did
App ID: com.myTeamName.myAppName ,
Service ID: com.myTeamName.myAppName.sid
Thank you so much.
https://docs.amplify.aws/gen1/react-native/build-a-backend/auth/add-social-provider/
